# MySQL: update different columns with separate conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Please how can I update different columns base on different and specific conditions. For example:

```sql
UPDATE table
SET col1 = val1 WHERE col1 > 2
SET col2 = val2 WHERE col2 > 1
```

Is is possible to write an SQL UPDATE statement like this
Where different columns will be updated base on separate conditions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `case`:

```
UPDATE table
    SET col1 = (CASE WHEN col1 > 2 THEN val1 ELSE col1 END),
        col2 = (CASE WHEN col2 > 1 THEN val2 ELSE col2 END);
```

You can also add `WHERE col1 > 2 or col2 > 1` so MySQL does not attempt to update all rows.